# Jquery autocomplete multiple dynamic input array

Tags: jquery

I have created a dynamic input arrray. It works fine for adding and deleting input fields. It also works fine for populating value in first input field. Problem is after adding multiple input fields, it does not work for autocomplete. The problem might be assiging each dynamic array identically and populate autocomplete accordingly. I have googled many times but did not find similar problem. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button><br>
        <div><input type="text" class="autoc" name="mytext[]" id="choice0"><input type="text" class="autoc" name="mynext[]" id="prid0"></div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        var availableAttributes = [
            {"label":"zia.khan@abc.net","value":"Business Planning & Supply Chain"},
            {"label":"mosharraf.hossain@abc.net","value":"Marketing"},
            {"label":"razib.mahmud@abc.net","value":"Sales"},
            {"label":"sadek.mohtadin@abc.net","value":"Technology"}
        ];
        
        
        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                var el = $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="choice' + (x - 1) + '"><input type="text" name="mynext[]" id="prid' + (x - 1) + '"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
                $(wrapper).append(el);

                el.find('input:eq(1)').autocomplete({
                    source: availableAttributes,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                       var parent =  $(this).parent("div");
                        parent.find("input:eq(0)").val(ui.item.label);
                        parent.find("input:eq(1)").val(ui.item.value);
                    }
                });
                //add input box
            }
        });
        
        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
        
        $("input[name^='mytext']").autocomplete({
            source: availableAttributes,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var parent =  $(this).parent("div");
                parent.find("input:eq(0)").val(ui.item.label);
                parent.find("input:eq(1)").val(ui.item.value);
            }
        }); 
        
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your selector when you try to bind the autocomplete for the newly added element,

```
$(wrapper).find('input[type=text]:last')
```

This selector does not match the newly added element given the way your DOM is structured, you would be better of adding a new class on the newly added `div` and then using that to select the inputs to bind the `autocomplete` as follows,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  var availableAttributes = [{
      "label": "zia.khan@abc.net",
      "value": "Business Planning & Supply Chain"
    },
    {
      "label": "mosharraf.hossain@abc.net",
      "value": "Marketing"
    },
    {
      "label": "razib.mahmud@abc.net",
      "value": "Sales"
    },
    {
      "label": "sadek.mohtadin@abc.net",
      "value": "Technology"
    }
  ];


  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="added"><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="choice' + (x - 1) + '"><input type="text" name="mynext[]" id="prid' + (x - 1) + '"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
      
      $('.added input').autocomplete({
        source: availableAttributes,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#choice' + (x - 1)).val(ui.item.label);
          $('#prid' + (x - 1)).val(ui.item.value);
        }
      });
      //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })

  $(".autoc:first-child").autocomplete({
    source: availableAttributes,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#choice' + (x - 1)).val(ui.item.label);
      $('#prid' + (x - 1)).val(ui.item.value);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button><br>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="autoc" name="mytext" id="choice0">
    <input type="text" class="autoc" name="mynext" id="prid0">
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

You will also need to wrap the `x-1` with parenthesis when you add your selector to update values,

```
$('#choice' + (x - 1))
```

Comment: Hello pai: Thanks for the solution. But it still does not autofill second input field.

Comment: @Tanvir updated my answer, you can use the `.autoc` class selector to bind autocomplete

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry but it does not update <input type="text" class="autoc" name="mynext" id="prid0">.. <input type="text" class="autoc" name="mynext" id="prid N">

Comment: Sorry from my side also. Each row there are two input fields. first input field autocomplete works but second input field should auto fill the value which does not work.

Comment: Sorry explaining agin. It should work like this 1st row 1st column autocomplete, 1st row 2nd column auto fill the value

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7PC/5/. I want this from 2nd row ....nth row

Comment: @Tanvir Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try it part of your code:

```
                 $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                        x++; //text box increment
                        var el = $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="choice' + (x - 1) + '"><input type="text" name="mynext[]" id="prid' + (x - 1) + '"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
                        $(wrapper).append(el);

                        el.find('input:eq(1)').autocomplete({
                            source: availableAttributes,
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                               var parent =  $(this).parent("div");
                                parent.find("input:eq(0)").val(ui.item.label);
                                parent.find("input:eq(1)").val(ui.item.value);
                            }
                        });
                        //add input box
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks toto. It works only for 1st row 1st column. But it should work for 1st row 2nd column. Also it does not work from 2nd row.

Comment: Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7PC/5/. I want this from 2nd row ....nth row

Comment: i observed that in your initial HTML code. <div> don´t end with enclose tag </div>

Comment: Yes got this. But still problem is not solved, sorry.

Comment: if you update el.find('input:eq(1)') using: el.find('input') ?

Comment: Hello todo, I don't know what change I have done. But now 1st row 1st column and 2nd column are working. But still it does not work from 2nd row. I have updated my question code. Could you please see code of my question please?